# Переход по сайту ТОЛЬКО по ссылкам

Tags: php

Хотел бы сделать, чтоб переход по страничкам возможен был только по ссылкам, я знаю есть такая штука -> `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` она работает, но если я бахну по Backspace меня перебрасывает на прошлую страницу, можно ли как то это убрать?)

Comment: >>но если я бахну по Backspace меня перебрасывает на прошлую страницу

Как это связано с вопросом?
А HTTP_REFERER, кстати, можно любой послать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Это история посещений браузера, тут ни как. И вообще не понятно зачем так делать?

Comment: Нужно =) Вот по этому спрашиваю

Comment: Так скажите цель. Так будет возможность предложить альтернативу.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сам придумал, спасибо большое =)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `PHP` это убрать не получится.